Utility of delete/reset members in copy assignement method
class B;

class A
{
 private:
   list<B*> myList;
   unique_ptr<B> smartUniq;
   

 public:
   A()
   {
      myList.push_back(new B(5));
      myList.push_back(new B(6));
      myList.push_back(new B(7));
   }

   ~A()
   {
      for (auto& item : myList)
      {
         
         delete item;
      }
      cout << "destructor"<<endl;
   }

   
   //Copy constructor
   A(const A &src)
   {
     for (auto& item : src.myList)
     {
       myList.push_back(new B(item->getb()));
     }
     smartUniq(make_unique<B>(*src.smartUniq))
   }
 
   /////////////////////////  VERSION1: Copy assignement  
   A& operator= (const A &src)
   {
     for (auto& item : myList)
     {
       if (item != nullptr)
          delete item;
     }
     
     for (auto& item : src.myList)
     {
       myList.push_back(new B(item->getb()));
     }
     smartUniq(make_unique<B>(*src.smartUniq))

     return *this;
   }

   /////////////////////////  VERSION2: Copy assignement  
   A& operator= (const A &src)
   {
     if( this != &src)
     {
         for (auto& item : src.myList)
         {
            myList.push_back(new B(item->getb()));
         }
         smartUniq.reset(src.smartUniq.get() ? make_unique<B>(*src.smartUniq) : nullptr);
     }

     return *this;
   }
};

Q1: which version of copy assignment is correct(Version1 or Version2 or other):

what is the utility to delete current members before copy?
what is the utility of :   if( this != &src)?

Q2: What is the utility of smartUniq.reset: is it possible to not use it as in VERSION1 ?

If there's one flaw in both functions, it is that both makes a copy of the unique smartUniq object. Your class A should not be copyable, only movable.

Thanks @Someprogrammerdude, how can i make a move not a copy of A with the 2 members?

When you post your code, please provide a minimal, reproducible example. This would include any includes and any using or using namespace (but don't!) statements.

As it stands, correcting those issues and compiling with g++ with -Wall -Wextra brings up a lot of warnings and errors.

There's no reason to add another indirection if A is supposed to own them. Whether you store list<B> or list<B*>, just use the list's copy constructor and destructor, and make A owning or non-owning respectively.

Your copy constructor and v1 copy assignment operator are not initializing/assigning the unique_ptr correctly.
Your copy assignment operator should not be resetting the unique_ptr at all if both A objects have valid B objects, it should just copy the B object directly.
Also, your v1 copy assignment operator is not clearing myList after destroying its items, so it is leaving dangling pointers in the list. And your v2 operator is not destroying the items at all.
Also, you should provide a move constructor and a move assignment operator, too.
Try this:
class A
{
 private:
   list<B*> myList;
   unique_ptr<B> smartUniq;

 public:
   A()
   {
      myList.push_back(new B(5));
      myList.push_back(new B(6));
      myList.push_back(new B(7));
   }

   ~A()
   {
      for (auto item : myList)
      {
         delete item;
      }
      cout << "destructor" <<endl;
   }

   A(const A &src)
   {
     for (auto item : src.myList)
     {
       myList.push_back(new B(item->getb()));
     }
     if (src.smartUniq)
     {
       smartUniq = make_unique<B>(*src.smartUniq);
     }
   }

   A(A &&src)
   {
     myList = std::move(src.myList);
     smartUniq = std::move(src.smartUniq);
   }

   A& operator= (const A &src)
   {
     if (this != &src)
     {
         for (auto item : myList)
         {
             delete item;
         }
         myList.clear();

         for (auto item : src.myList)
         {
            myList.push_back(new B(item->getb()));
         }

         if (src.smartUniq)
         {
             if (smartUniq)
                 *smartUniq = *src.smartUniq;
             else
                 smartUniq = make_unique<B>(*src.smartUniq);
         }
         else
             smartUniq.reset();
     }

     return *this;
   }

   A& operator= (A &&src)
   {
     myList = std::move(src.myList);
     smartUniq = std::move(src.smartUniq);
     return *this;
   }
};

